# Call jQuery function from Rails link_to

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have a ruby loop that creates a list of comments..

I wonder if I can attach jQuery function to  Rails link_to helper in this case?

```
    <% @video.phrases.each do |phrase| %> 
    <div class = "span4" id ="comment" ><%= phrase.content %></div><a id ="ff"  ><%= image_tag("ff.png", :size=> "32x32" )%></a>
    <% end %>
```

I am hoping for something like

```
    <% @video.phrases.each do |phrase| %> 
    <div class = "span4" id ="comment" ><%= phrase.content %></div><%= link_to (image_tag("ff.png", :size=> "32x32" ), html => {<script>$("#video_div").html('CONTENTS OF HTML');</script>} :remote => true %>
    <% end %>
```

I know it won't work, but I wonder is there an easy way to achieve this kind of functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this two ways.

The first is the add an html attribute on the link_to:

```
<% @video.phrases.each do |phrase| %> 
  <div class = "span4" id ="comment" >
    <%= phrase.content %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to (image_tag("ff.png", :size=> "32x32" ), html => {:onclick => "$('#video_div').html('CONTENTS OF HTML');"} :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

The second is to separate the Javascript from Ruby:

```
<% @video.phrases.each do |phrase| %> 
  <div class = "span4" id ="comment" >
    <%= phrase.content %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to (image_tag("ff.png", :size=> "32x32" ) :remote => true %>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('a').click(function(){
    $("#video_div").html('CONTENTS OF HTML');
  );
</script>
```

If you want the contents of the link tag, substitute `'CONTENTS OF HTML'` for `$(this).html()`

Answer (score 3):

Also I actually found out about Rails link_to_function helper and was able to achieve the desired behavior with:

```
<% @video.phrases.each do |phrase| %> 
 <div class = "span4" id ="comment" ><%= phrase.content %></div><a id ="ff">
  <%= link_to_function image_tag("ff.png", :size=> "32x32" ), "use_comment('#{phrase.comment}')"%>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use event delegation, since it seems like you'll be creating a large number of comments.

So, borrowing from grant something like:

```
<% @video.phrases.each do |phrase| %> 
  <div class = "span4" id ="comment" >
    <%= phrase.content %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to (image_tag("ff.png", :size=> "32x32" ) :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#comment-wrapper-name-here").on("click", "a", function() {
    $("#video_div").html('CONTENTS OF HTML');
  );
</script>
```